# Return multiple values in different cells or list

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Hi everyone i am trying to find a function on vba that will return multiple values in different cells.
So for example I have a table with:

```
column 1 Column 2
hey          d11
htt          s56
hey          7y9j
bbht         hfhhf
hey          678dh
```

I want to look for 'hey' and get all the corresponding values in different cells or list.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You could quickly just Filter the data in Column 1 to show "Hey", then copy/paste? What have you tried? Do you need VBA? I assume you want to return, in a list, `d11`,`7y9j`, and `678h`?

Comment: This is tagged with `vba`, have you tried anything?  This can also be done with a filter (easiest method, but manual), or with formulas: https://www.excelforum.com/tips-and-tutorials/947848-lookup-a-value-and-return-multiple-results.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this out (without VBA) and let me know in case of any queries or if you require detailed explanation.

**Step1:** `Filter` the data by column A.
**Step2:** Make a new column C where use this formula `IF(A2=A1,CONCATENATE(B2,",",C1),B2)` .
**Step3:** Make a new column D where use this formula `IF(A2=A3," ","REQUIRED_ANS")` .
**Step4:** `Filter` on column D using `ALT` + `D` + `F` + `F` and you get you desired output